# Change resolution of half-degree netCDF to quarter degree netCDF using nco tools

Tags: python, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I can change the resolution of a netCDF file to a coarser one by doing something like this:

```
ncks --dmn lon,0,1384,5 --dmn lat,0,583,4 original.nc reduced.nc
```

How do I go the other way? I.e. change resolution of coarser scale netCDF to finer scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing resolution with NCO requires [regridding](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#regrid), available in NCO 4.5.1+. This currently requires you have a SCRIP/ESMF-compliant mapfile, which can be generated from SCRIP-compliant [gridfiles](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#grid) with, e.g., ESMF_RegridWeightGen. You would need to install ESMF, a simple package on many free OS's, e.g., on MacPorts 'port install esmf'.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the remapping facilities in cdo

```
cdo remapcon,gridfile.txt in.nc out.nc
```

You need to specify a grid description in the gridfile.txt file, e.g. containing the first lat/lon, number of points and the increment:

```
gridtype = lonlat
xsize = nlon
ysize = nlat
xfirst = lon1
xinc = dlon
yfirst = lat1
yinc = dlat
```

or you can also set the grid specification directly

```
cdo remapcon,grid-specification in.nc out.nc
```

so to remap to a regular 720 by 360 lon-lat grid you can do

```
cdo remapcon,r720x360 in.nc out.nc
```

Note that the "con" in "remapcon" stands for "conservative" remapping.  There are other remapping options available, such as 2nd order conservative remapping (remapcon2), bilinear interpolation (remapbil), nearest neighbour remapping (remapnn) and more... see the documention for further details:

https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html